# How to make jQuery animate({bottom... work

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser

I'm trying to create a simple animation in which a block of text drops down into its containing div when that div is hovered over.

I created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/EFhVp/1/

For some reason my code works perfectly as expected in Firefox, but not in Chrome or jsfiddle.

What's happens in Firefox (expected): the hidden text dropping down (from the top) when I mouse over and then rising back up on mouse off the container

What happens in chrome and jfiddle: the text sort of shoots upward and then disappears on mouse off.

I suspect there's something unexpected happening when I animate the "bottom:" property but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `bottom` property was a strange approach. I've converted your code to use `top` instead and the animation works cross-browser: http://jsfiddle.net/EFhVp/2/

```
$(function() {
    $(".projectgrid .entry-content").hover(function() {
        $(".projecttags", this).animate({
            top: "0px"
        }, "slow");
    }, function() {
        $(".projecttags", this).animate({
            top: "-100%"
        }, "slow");
    }
    );
});​
```

Comment: On a different note: the reason I used the "bottom" property was to place the inner div just above the container. I see how your version simpler using `top:"-100%"` but the downside is that there's a lag between when the user mouses over and when the animated div appears (because it's starting from way above the top of the container). Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Yes, there are a couple of approaches here: if you know the height of the caption will be constant across all instances, you can change -100% to -50px (or the actual height) in CSS and JS; if you can't guarantee that, then you could calculate the outerHeight on load and offset each of the captions by that height with JS.

Comment: Perfect. The caption height is not consistent. The outerHeight solution is actually what I was about to do before posting this question, so I feel great about that. Is it terrible to calculate the outerHeight within the .hover() function as opposed to storing all the different caption heights as variables?

For any other jQuery newbies that might find this: be careful about confusing `.height()` with `.outerHeight()`. Only the latter includes the padding, so it's the one you need for this kind of thing. This confused me at first because I think of padding as an "inside" thing.

Comment: You can calculate the outerHeight once and then re-use the value. Calculating it on load is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
     $('.projectgrid .entry-content').hover(
function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({marginTop:'-25px',}, 300);  
    },
    function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({marginTop:'0px',}, 1000);
    }
);
```

Try this one. it works for me in all browser

Comment: I haven't tried this but it animates the container (.entry-content) as opposed to the inside div.